# CSOM - Get root site collection URL

Tags: site-collection, csom

I'm trying to evaluate the position of users, defining whether they come from a site (`test.sharepoint.com/sites/site1`) or if they reside at the root site collection (`test.sharepoint.com`).

Does CSOM have any way of achieving this?

If I'm at `test.sharepoint.com/sites/site1`, can I get the root site collection of that?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to check if the user is at the root web application site collection (not nested under a managed path) ?

Comment: Correct. I as hoping that the `ClientContext` would have information about this, but I can't seem to find any. Something `context.Site.Parent` or something similar.

Comment: @Detilium, Is my answer works for you?

Comment: @Hardik Your example shows how to do this with JSOM. I'm looking for a way to do this with CSOM.

Comment: Please refer the links which i had provided in my answer. it will help you for both server side & client side code. I have also updated my answer as well so please look into it....... Thanks

Answer (score 8):

**CSOM**

Using the ClientContext, get your Site object and check its URL

```
SPContext.Current.Site.ServerRelativeUrl : if == "/"
```

**JSOM**

For that you can use the `_spPageContextInfo` variable.

To check if user is in root site collection vs any other site collection, check this variable :
`_spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl` : if == "/", then is the absolute root site collection

To check if user is in a subsite vs site collection, compare those variables :

`_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl` : current absolute URL
`_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl` : current site collection absolute URL

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I'm looking for a server-side way of achieving this.

Comment: My bad, too much into JSOM !

Answer (score 1):

`SPSite.RootWeb` is the object you're after, in server side code ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.rootweb.aspx).

`SP.Site.get_rootWeb()` in client object model code ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee552834.aspx).

**To get root site collection,**

```
SPSite rootSiteCollection = mySiteCollection.WebApplication.Sites[0];
```

Below is the sample code to get ROOT Site Collection.

```
var clientContext;
var siteCollection;

// Make sure the SharePoint script file 'sp.js' is loaded before your
// code runs.
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', sharePointReady);

// Create an instance of the current context and get the site collection.
function sharePointReady() {
    clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    siteCollection = clientContext.get_site();

    clientContext.load(siteCollection);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSucceeded, onRequestFailed);
}
function onRequestSucceeded() {
    alert('URL of the root website: ' + siteCollection.get_url());
}
function onRequestFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Error: ' + args.get_message());
}
```

Comment: SPSite is not about CSOM, it is serverside developing.